# R forest plot superscript in author list

Tags: r, superscript, r-forestplot

I want to create a forest plot and I have to put the reference as a superscript in the forest plot.

I have tried several things.

Suppose this in my authors list en the references

```
   aut<- c("a, 2018", "c, 2018", "v, 2018", "f, 2018", "f, 2017", 
            "f, 2015", "y, 2014","ya, 2014","y, 2014","j, 2013", "j, 2011",
            "j, 2011","h, 2011", "g, 2011","e, 2010","r, 2008","f, 2008",
            "gh, 2007","h, 2006","h, 2005","h, 2004","h, 2003",
            "h, 2002", "g, 2002","f, 2002","f, 2001","f, 2001", "208136/016, 2001", "208136/007, 2001",
            "f, 2000","f, 2000", "g, 1999","g, 1999", "g, 1998",
            "d , 1998","g, 1998","go, 1997","g, 1995","g, 1994",
            "r, 1991","r, 1989","r, 1988","r, 1987","r, 1983",
            "g, 1982","g, 1981","g, 1975","g, 1975")
    ref<-as.character(seq(1:48))
```

I tried the following:

```
aut2<-parse(text(paste(expression(aut,"^",ref))))
```

But I get an error:

```
    Error in parse(text(paste(expression(aut, "^", number)))) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection
In addition: Warning message:
In xy.coords(x, y, recycle = TRUE, setLab = FALSE) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

I also tried with expression but that did not work either.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: I found a solution! Never mind

Comment: Hey, it would be great if you could answer your own question so others can be helped by the solution you found!

Answer (score 0):

So i found a sollution. Not prettiest but it does the trick and I was not in the mood to search for something elagant.

```
aut<-list(expression("author,2011"^2,.. etc)
```

Where 2 is the reference.

It was more mater of finding the right format that I needed for putting stuff together in the forestplot function

I hope this could help others too :)

Comment: aut<-list(expression("author,2011"^2),.. etc) ***